# Rendering a map with a tooltip in React/D3

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to create a tooltip for my map of NYC precincts in my react-app, using D3.  I would like the tooltip to appear when I hover over a precinct, displaying the precinct number.  Right now, I can get the precinct number to appear correctly, but I can't get the tooltip's div element to follow the mouse - it stays on the upper left corner of the screen.  Is there a way to get the div element to change its position relative to mouse position?  (I can't seem to get the element to respond to the changing "left" and "top" style attributes, that ARE changing as the mouse changes position.)

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { usePrecinctsMap } from './context/precinctsMapContext'
import * as d3 from "d3";

export const PrecinctsMap = props => {

    const data = usePrecinctsMap()

    const svgRef = useRef()
    const containerRef = useRef()
    const tltpRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        var tooltip = d3.select(tltpRef.current)
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .attr("position", "absolute")
        .style("opacity", 0);

        const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current)
            .attr("height", 500)
            .attr("width", "100%")

        const projection = d3.geoAlbers().fitExtent([[20, 20], [300, 300]], data)

        const pathGenerator = d3.geoPath().projection(projection)

        svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(data.features)
        .join("path")
        .attr('d', pathGenerator)
        .attr('class', 'precinct')
        .attr('fill', 'transparent')
        .attr('stroke', '#999999')
        .attr('stroke-width', '1')
        .on("mouseover", function(event,d) {
            tooltip.style("left", (event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("top", (event.pageY - 28) + "px");  
        tooltip.transition()
         .duration(200)
         .style("opacity", .9)
         ;
        tooltip.text(d.properties.precinct);
       })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
       tooltip.transition()
         .duration(500)
         .style("opacity", 0);
       });
    }, [containerRef.current])

    return (
        
        <div ref={containerRef} style={{ marginBottom: "2rem" }}>
            <div ref={tltpRef}></div>
      <svg ref={svgRef}></svg>
      
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What does your css for the tooltip look like?

Comment: all the css is currently in the code - position: absolute, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change your position style from absolute to fixed.

Then in your javascript, reference event.clientX + 'px' and event.clientY + 'px' in place of pageY and pageX.

Comment: thanks - still no luck.  the tooltip div doesn't move and just stays in the corner.

Comment: When inspecting, does the left and top value of your tooltip change? I wonder if the parenthesis around your event references could be causing an issue.

Comment: the tooltip left and top values do change - that's what's so confusing to me.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with react lifecycles and re-rendering..